# AzureDevops yml pipeline, how to merge a list of steps from foreach into one step

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

> **tldr**

right now the validation template creates a list of tasks

```
steps:
- ${{ each dependsOnVariable in parameters.dependsOnVariables }}:
```

**Question**: is there a way to tweak the template logic to combine all the checks into a single task?

---

> **Detailed Version**

We are tring to make reusable yml templates(mostly ps1 script steps).
When we pass values to that template, we cannot use `parameters` for any runtime values.
So, we decided to use `variables` with macro syntax inside those tasks.

but the problem is that we cannot ensure that the dependent variables are being passed before the unit of work inside the template actually runs.

to workaround that, we decided to create a validation template with a step, which can be run before any further steps are called.

```
//template file:validate-dependent-variables.yml
parameters:
  - name: dependsOnVariables
    type: object
    default: {} 

steps:
- ${{ each dependsOnVariable in parameters.dependsOnVariables }}:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: validate dependent variable ${{ dependsOnVariable }}
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
        #variable is present if its value is not equal to its literal replacement        
        $variable = "`$`(${{ dependsOnVariable }})"
        $variableValue = '$(${{ dependsOnVariable }})'
        $variableValueIspresent = $variable -ne  $variableValue
        Write-Host variableValueIspresent=$variableValueIspresent
        if(!$variableValueIspresent)
        {
          Write-Error "variable $variable is not passed in"
          Exit
        }
```

and the usage

```
//do-something-task.yml
jobs:
  - job: DoSomethingJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImage)
    steps:
      - template: 'validate-dependent-variables.yml'  
        parameters:
          dependsOnVariables:
            - appServiceResourceGroupName
            - appServiceName
            - packageVersion
            
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Run something useful
        inputs:
          pwsh: true
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host "$(appServiceResourceGroupName)"
            Write-Host "$(appServiceName)"
            Write-Host "$(packageVersion)"
```

The logic is to compare the literal usage of the variable, e.g. $(packageVersion), to its replaced runtime value, e.g. "1.2.3"

```
"$(packageVersion)" = "$(packageVersion)" ##validation failed
"$(packageVersion)" = "1.2.3"  ##validation successful
```

When the pipeline runs, the script in the tasks(that is genereated for each parameter) looks like below before executing

```
$variable = "`$`(packageVersion)"
$variableValue = '$(packageVersion)'
$variableValueIspresent = $variable -ne  $variableValue
Write-Host variableValueIspresent=$variableValueIspresent
if(!$variableValueIspresent)
{
  Write-Error "variable $variable is not passed in"
  Exit
}
```

The problem is that this creates one task for each variable.
[image]

right now the validation template creates a list of tasks at runtime. We cannot have `each` inside the script block, so the `each` is on the step level

```
steps:
- ${{ each dependsOnVariable in parameters.dependsOnVariables }}:
```

**Question**: is there a way to tweak the template logic to combine all the checks into a single task?

---

Comment: Have you tried the `$[ ... ]` notation? That should result in an empty string when no value is present.

Comment: my issue is the foreach of the step which creates too many steps at runtime, not the body of the script itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `convertToJson` function to convert a YAML `object` to JSON, which can then be parsed in your PowerShell script and used however you'd like.

Comment: I didn't understand how parsing something in the script at step runtime be of any use if the variable  values are not replaced at the yml compilation step.

Comment: '$(${{ dependsOnVariable }})' -> '$(var1)' compile time -> 'actualValue' run time. I have to compare '$(var1)' against 'actualValue' at runtime. when there is a value, it is replaced, when not is left as is.